# NetBeans IDE: Is there a way to make files read-only or lock the contents?

Tags: java, netbeans, ide, readonly, file-locking

In the Netbeans IDE, is there a way to make a file read-only
or prevent the file's contents from being edited, even though
the file is part of a project as source code, a test package, or a data file?

PLEASE NOTE: I know a version control system should be used for any kind
of project, and I diff any file with the version control copy 
before committing the changes to the repository; I'm just wondering if there's a way to "lock" a file in this editor/IDE.

Comment: Doing that in NB won't really help. Anybody can just open the file in another editor. You really ought to track (or enforce if possible) those sorts of things in your source code control system.

Comment: Yes, I have a version control system; and as a safeguard, I always "diff" the file in SVN before committing - I was just wondering if there is a way to do this in NB - thanks.

Comment: Give it read-only permissions on the filesystem

Comment: In your Source Control System seems a little late to be handling mistakenly modified files. Why not avoid the problem in the first place? When you *know* you are perusing a source file with no intent to edit, it would convenient to open the file as read-only inside NetBeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research, this feature appears to have been added as an add on:

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/23133/switch-file-read-write-access

http://kenai.com/projects/file-rw-switcher/pages/Home