# How do I make readonly file writable in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-6.9, netbeans-plugins

I am using Netbeans 6.9.1.

Whenever I open `readonly` file and want to edit it I have to go to file directory manually and remove the `readonly` flag from properties.

Is there any plug-in or some way we can do directly make it writable in netbeans editor itself?

Comment: I think this thread will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288668/netbeans-ide-is-there-a-way-to-make-files-read-only-or-lock-the-contents